# iOS peers cannot connect to video call - NotAllowedError raised

Tags: ios, webrtc, mobile-safari, peerjs

PeerJS: 1.3.2

Tested on: iOS 15 & 13.

I have the below call service file that implements PeerJS functionality to init, establish and answer video calls.

Calls work as expected across Android devices, macOS and PCs.

However, when attempting to join from an iOS device, we see the following error raised:

```
NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent 
or the platform in the current context, possibly because the
user denied permission.
```

call-service.js:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import Peer from 'peerjs';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


@Injectable()
export class CallService {

    private peer: Peer;
    private mediaCall: Peer.MediaConnection;
  
    private localStreamBs: BehaviorSubject<MediaStream> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    public localStream$ = this.localStreamBs.asObservable();
    private remoteStreamBs: BehaviorSubject<MediaStream> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    public remoteStream$ = this.remoteStreamBs.asObservable();

    private isCallStartedBs = new Subject<boolean>();
    public isCallStarted$ = this.isCallStartedBs.asObservable();

    constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

    public initPeer(): string {
        if (!this.peer || this.peer.disconnected) {
            const peerJsOptions: Peer.PeerJSOption = {
                debug: 3,
                config: {
                    iceServers: [
                        {
                            urls: [
                                'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
                                'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
                            ],
                        }]
                }
            };
            try {
                let id = uuidv4();
                this.peer = new Peer(id, peerJsOptions);
                return id;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    }

    public async establishMediaCall(remotePeerId: string) {
        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true});

            
            let peerOptions: any = {};
            
            if (this.checkSafari()) {
              peerOptions.serialization = "json";
            }
            
            const connection = this.peer.connect(remotePeerId, peerOptions);
            connection.on('error', err => {
              console.error(err);
              this.snackBar.open(err, 'Close');
            });
            
            this.mediaCall = this.peer.call(remotePeerId, stream);
            if (!this.mediaCall) {
              let errorMessage = 'Unable to connect to remote peer';
              this.snackBar.open(errorMessage, 'Close');
              throw new Error(errorMessage);
            }
            this.localStreamBs.next(stream);
            this.isCallStartedBs.next(true);

            this.mediaCall.on('stream',
                (remoteStream) => {
                    this.remoteStreamBs.next(remoteStream);
                });
            this.mediaCall.on('error', err => {
                this.snackBar.open(err, 'Close');
                console.error(err);
                this.isCallStartedBs.next(false);
            });
            this.mediaCall.on('close', () => this.onCallClose());
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.error(ex);
            this.snackBar.open(ex, 'Close');
            this.isCallStartedBs.next(false);
        }
    }

    public async enableCallAnswer() {
        try {
          let peerOptions: any = {};
          
          if (this.checkSafari()) {
            peerOptions.serialization = "json";
          }
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
            this.localStreamBs.next(stream);
            this.peer.on('call', async (call) => {
    
                this.mediaCall = call;
                this.isCallStartedBs.next(true);
    
                this.mediaCall.answer(stream);
                this.mediaCall.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
                    this.remoteStreamBs.next(remoteStream);
                });
                this.mediaCall.on('error', err => {
                    this.snackBar.open(err, 'Close');
                    this.isCallStartedBs.next(false);
                    console.error(err);
                });
                this.mediaCall.on('close', () => this.onCallClose());
            });            
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.error(ex);
            this.snackBar.open(ex, 'Close');
            this.isCallStartedBs.next(false);            
        }
    }

    private onCallClose() {
        this.remoteStreamBs?.value.getTracks().forEach(track => {
            track.stop();
        });
        this.localStreamBs?.value.getTracks().forEach(track => {
            track.stop();
        });
        this.snackBar.open('Call Ended', 'Close');
    }

    public closeMediaCall() {
        this.mediaCall?.close();
        if (!this.mediaCall) {
            this.onCallClose()
        }
        this.isCallStartedBs.next(false);
    }

    public destroyPeer() {
        this.mediaCall?.close();
        this.peer?.disconnect();
        this.peer?.destroy();
    }

    public checkSafari() {
      let seemsChrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > -1;
      let seemsSafari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;
      return seemsSafari && !seemsChrome;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing. This was a local permissions issue on my test device and no fault of PeerJS.
Reinstalling Chrome on iOS then enabled the relevant camera permissions